# In Scala Play Framework, is there a simple way to verify signatures on form requests

Tags: scala, playframework, hmac

I am trying to write a Scala Play Framework action that will verify a HmacSHA256 signature on an incoming POST request containing form-url-encoded data.

This does not seem straightforward in the Play framework because: i) actions builders only have access to headers, but do not have access to the request body, and ii) in order to calculate the signature we have to treat the request body as `Array[ByteString]`, but when we come to process the form data we have to treat it as `Map[String, Seq[String]]`, the problem being thatPlay forces us to choose a single type for our request, and we cannot easily "cast" the request body to a different type.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to use an `ActionRefiner` that returns a `WrappedRequest` that embeds a callback to validate the signature.  The callback in turn reparses the data using `FormUrlEncodedParser.parse(new String(request.body.toArray))`.  This approach is illustrated in the code below.

This all seems overly convoluted.  Is there a simpler way to verify Hmac signatures in Play, or am I simply running up against limitations of the API?

```scala
package actions

import akka.util.ByteString
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.Logging
import play.api.mvc.Results.Unauthorized
import play.api.mvc._
import play.core.parsers.FormUrlEncodedParser
import services.SlackSignatureVerifierService

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.Try

class SlackRequest[A](
    val validateSignature: String => Try[String],
    request: Request[A]
) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object SlackSignatureVerifyAction {

  implicit class SlackRequestByteStringValidator(
      slackRequest: SlackRequest[ByteString]
  ) {
    def validateSignatureAgainstBody(): Try[Map[String, Seq[String]]] = {
      val raw = slackRequest.body.utf8String
      slackRequest.validateSignature(raw) map { _ =>
        FormUrlEncodedParser.parse(new String(slackRequest.body.toArray))
      }
    }
  }

  val HEADERS_TIMESTAMP: String = "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp"
  val HEADERS_SIGNATURE: String = "X-Slack-Signature"
}

class SlackSignatureVerifyAction @Inject() (
    val parser: BodyParsers.Default,
    slackSignatureVerifierService: SlackSignatureVerifierService
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends ActionBuilder[SlackRequest, AnyContent]
    with ActionRefiner[Request, SlackRequest]
    with Logging {

  override protected def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec

  override protected def refine[A](
      request: Request[A]
  ): Future[Either[Result, SlackRequest[A]]] = {

    val timestamp =
      request.headers.get(SlackSignatureVerifyAction.HEADERS_TIMESTAMP)

    val signature =
      request.headers.get(SlackSignatureVerifyAction.HEADERS_SIGNATURE)

    (timestamp, signature) match {
      case (Some(timestamp), Some(signature)) =>
        Future.successful {
          val validate = (body: String) =>
            slackSignatureVerifierService.validate(timestamp, body, signature)
          Right(new SlackRequest[A](validate, request))
        }
      case _ =>
        Future { Left(Unauthorized("Invalid signature headers")) }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new Play module to validate Hmac signatures.  Details can be found here:

https://github.com/phelps-sg/play-hmac-signatures

Answer (score 1):

You are right, **there isn't an easy way to verify Hmac signatures on Play!** projects. In the end, your approach seems to have a very reasonable implementation and could be easier adapted to other providers, such as GitHub and Stripe, that uses Hmac signatures.

I really think it could be a good open-source project to provide an `Action` with a wrapped `Request` or even a `Service` with a method to do custom signature validation for other providers. Why don't you help the Play community with an open-source project over GitHub?

Comment: I have opened a new issue here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/11507